# How To pull a text html attribute using HTMLabilityPack

Tags: c#, html, discord.net

I need to pull the highlighted text from this [Site](https://pubgtracker.com/profile/pc/SilentFOG?region=agg) I am using the code below and getting the error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I am Also using this [Guide](http://html-agility-pack.net/select-nodes) in the guide it says use Xpath expression. I go to the line i want and right click => copy => copy xpath. I get //*[@id="profile"]/div[2](http://html-agility-pack.net/select-nodes)/div[2](http://html-agility-pack.net/select-nodes)/div[1](https://pubgtracker.com/profile/pc/SilentFOG?region=agg)/div[1](https://pubgtracker.com/profile/pc/SilentFOG?region=agg)/div[1](https://pubgtracker.com/profile/pc/SilentFOG?region=agg)/div[1](https://pubgtracker.com/profile/pc/SilentFOG?region=agg)/div/text()"); I have to escape the quotes. If i just do "//*[@id="profile"]" then it works fine and i get profile, but i just cant get this to work and get the stat.

EDIT: What I need is to get the rank value. But i cannot simply call that one rank because rank is used for Solo, FPP Solo, and so on. But i am trying to get he "1,510,890" number currently.

[image: Trying to get Highlighted Text]

```
[Command("test")]
[Alias("ti")]
public async Task Stats(string name)
{
    string path = "https://pubgtracker.com/profile/pc/" + name + "?region=agg";
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument Doc = web.Load(path);

    var htmlNodes = Doc.DocumentNode
                    .SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"profile\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/text()");

    foreach (var node in htmlNodes)
    {
        foreach (var att in node.Attributes)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(att.Value); 
        }                    
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the `<div>` with class "rank" is only in the document once, why not just grab that with `"//div[contains(@class, 'rank')]"`

Comment: rank is used in 5+ more instances in  //*[@id="profile"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/text() it is used again for solofpp Also if i try that it just calls back the "rank"

Comment: Its super unclear what you need.  Do you need _one specific_ div with class = "rank"?  It looks like you are iterating through all of them in your example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: My previous answer is no longer valid, please read my new findings below.

---

I do not think what you are trying to do currently is possible.

It seems that the data that displays your Solo rank (and tons of other data) is being loaded in after the HTML is loaded (meaning that the javascript in the browser is handling some databinding after the html has been downloaded).

You can test this yourself in two ways:

1. Put a debugger on the `HtmlDocument Doc = web.Load(path);` line in your code, and check the value of `Doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml`, copy and paste this into Notepad++ or another text editor and look at the data thats there.  You will find that your rank is not loaded by the server (i.e its not available in the source HTML)
2. Instead of inspecting element on the page in Chrome, right click and "View Source". This is the same data that HtmlAgilityPack sees when it "loads" the HTML into the object.  It does not allow javascript to run (meaning your values are never bound to any HTML).

The *only* way I can see to gather the data you need is to get the javascript object that is embedded in the source from the server.  You will see it towards the end of the document in a `<script>` tag.  Its a *giant* javscript object that (among other things) contains your rank.

You can see this for yourself by viewing the source like I explained above, and doing a Ctrl+F for your rank.  You will see it show up in two places in the object.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. When i tried this

Comment: Ok, so on what line was that exception thrown?

Comment: Console.WriteLine(soloRankNode.InnerText); has the error

Comment: HtmlNode soloNode = Doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[text() = 'Solo']"); has the error actually sorry

Comment: @JacobLenertz why are you scraping the HTML to begin with, they have an [API](https://pubgtracker.com/site-api).  Go register then fire a GET request to "https://pubgtracker.com/api/profile/pc/SilentFOG"

Comment: API has been removed This is because as of a few days ago Bluehole implemented strict throttling for everyone.

In order to keep our site functional we had to disable some additional features we provide like the API. from the devs

Comment: Well if you take a look at the Html retrieved from the HtmlAgilityPack load, you will notice none of your stats are in the source.  All that must be done via javascript on the client.  However they do drop a giant javascript object on the page you could potentially grab

Comment: Yeah i noticed that but i don't understand why you can look up someones stats like the one i linked and it is displayed but you can grab that number.

Comment: But if i did do that what would be the best route to take ??

Comment: I edited my answer to add some new insight.  Check it out